# YouTube iframe API Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube-api

I have run into a confusing issue. Everything has been working just fine and all of the sudden I started getting this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: playervid.isMuted is not a function`

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

here is the code

```
// 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement('script');

tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

jQuery.noConflict()(function($) {

// 3. This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
//    after the API code downloads.
var playervid;

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  playervid = new YT.Player('playervid', {
    height: "720",
    width: "1280",
    videoId: 'JNsFY9Hr-OU',
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 1, 'showinfo': 0, 'controls': 0, 'autohide': 1, 'rel': 0, 'wmode': 'transparent'},
    events: {
      'onReady': initialize,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });

}

function initialize(event){
    event.target.mute();
}

$('body').on('click', '#mute-toggle', function(event) {

var mute_toggle = $(this);
if(playervid.isMuted()){
  playervid.unMute();
  mute_toggle.html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  $('.video-container iframe').removeClass('blur');
}
else{
  playervid.mute();
  mute_toggle.html('<i class="fa fa-volume-up fa-2x muted" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
  $('.video-container iframe').addClass('blur');
}
}
```

When the user clicks the `#mute-toggle` button I get the error.

Comment: Could you try reproduce the problem in a snippet or maybe using **https://jsfiddle.net/** You don't have to include all of the source code, only the relevant parts to give a working example of the issue you are currently dealing with. Thank you.

Comment: How about I give the url to the dev site

Comment: I would much rather have a working example as I don't really like opening unknown domains but I think on this occasion since it will save time, sure... :) I will check it out and see if I can find the problem and solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Turns out the theme I am using "Divi" ran an update that now runs some javascript when you select a transparent background for the menu bar and this was effecting the API. I wrapped the call to the API in a setTimeout function and it started working again.